# What software can draw pictures like this?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I used Mathematica to draw a function picture, but it is not beautiful like the picture below. I want know what software can draw  beautiful pictures like the one below.

This picture is from [the Wikipedia article on Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration).

> [image: Coloured diagram]

Comment: More about this [here](http://nilesjohnson.net/hopf.html) (possibly...)

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at [Software Recommendation SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Both existing answers say that it is done in Sage, but it is only partially true. The visualization was not done in Sage itself. The image is ray-traced. Niles Johnson, author of the image, used Tachyon, an open source raytracer.

So in order to follow similar workflow my recommendation would be:

1. Generate data in Sage, Mathematica or similar mathematical package. By data I mean like the ring positions and color.
2. Generate geometry. You need to generate actual polygonal meshes which will be rendered. This might be possible to do in Mathematica or Sage but I would use a 3d program such as Autodesk Maya, 3ds Max or Blender.
3. Render the geometry. Use ray-tracer to render geometry. You can use open-source renderer such as Tachyon, Mitsuba or use comercial such as V-Ray, Mental Ray.

I would probably do everything in Blender, because it supports Python. I would download some math library, e.g. numpy, to make the data generation easier, then I can generate the geometry directly and Blender has a built-in ray-tracer, which can be used for rendering.

Comment: Actually sage provides a interface to the raytracer, do the author **did** use sage for the rendering as an end user. Also note that he did not use his laptop or desktop to produce the video. He says he used a 24 processor machines from the university  and it took 40 hours to complete

Comment: @Bakuriu: But note that the 960 processor-hours was for computing the entire animation (about 162 seconds). If you assume 10 frames per second (which is likely low), you get that each individual frame took about 36 minutes of processor time. So a single picture (as requested by the OP) might well be feasible on a laptop or desktop.

Comment: Recently I have started using Houdini for my visualizations. For anyone interested. I would recommend reading this blog http://wordpress.discretization.de/houdini/

Answer (score 32):

The beauty of the picture above is not primarily a question of the software used, but rather the time and effort that went into it. In principle, the only thing software has to be able to do is to plot a parametrized surface with parametrized colors. Here's a picture similar to Niles Johnson's (but with only 2-3 hours invested, and correspondingly less magnificent) produced using the free [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) software package, and taking only a couple seconds to compile on a laptop:

[image]

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render = 4;
import graph3;
defaultrender.tubegranularity=1e-3;

size(20cm);

currentprojection = orthographic(-5,-4,2);

typedef triple surfaceparam(pair);
typedef pair curveparam(real);

surfaceparam revolve(curveparam F) {
  return new triple(pair uv) {
    real t = uv.x, theta = uv.y;
    pair rz = F(t);
    real r = rz.x, z = rz.y;
    return (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta), z);
  };
}

pair circlecenter(real r) {
  return r + 1 / (1 + r);
}

curveparam circleparam(real r) {
  pair center = circlecenter(r);
  return new pair(real t) {
    return center + r * expi(2 pi * t);
  };
}

surfaceparam torusparam(real r) { return revolve(circleparam(r)); }

surfaceparam hopfparam(real r) {
  surfaceparam mytorus = torusparam(r);
  return new triple(pair uv) {
    return mytorus((uv.x, 2 pi * (uv.y - uv.x)));
  };
}

surface surface(triple f(pair z), pair a, pair b, int nu=nmesh, int nv=nu,
        bool smooth=true, pen color(pair z)) {
  surface s = smooth ? surface(f, a, b, nu, nv, Spline) : surface(f, a, b, nu, nv);
  real delta_u = (b.x - a.x)/nu;
  real delta_v = (b.y - a.y)/nv;
  for (int i = 0; i < nu; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nv; ++j) {
      patch currentpatch = s.s[s.index[i][j]];
      pair z = (interp(a.x, b.x, i/nu), interp(a.y, b.y, j/nv));
      currentpatch.colors = new pen[];
      currentpatch.colors.push(color(z));
      currentpatch.colors.push(color(z + (delta_u, 0)));
      currentpatch.colors.push(color(z + (delta_u, delta_v)));
      currentpatch.colors.push(color(z + (0, delta_v)));
    }
  }
  return s;
}

real rescale(real t) { return atan((pi/2)*t) / (pi / 2); }

for (real r : new real[] {0.2, 0.8, 2.0}) {
  pen color(pair uv) {
    real z = 2 * rescale(r) - 1;
    if (z > 1)  z = 1;
    else if (z < -1) z = -1;
    real cylradius = sqrt(1 - z^2);
    real theta = 2pi * uv.y;
    real x = cylradius * cos(theta), y = cylradius * sin(theta);
    x = (x+1)/2; y = (y+1)/2; z = (z+1)/2;
    return x*red + y*green + z*blue;
  }
  int nu = 8, nv = 8;
  surface s = surface(hopfparam(r), (0,0), (1,1/2), nu, nv, smooth=true, color=color);
  draw(s);
  for (int j = 0; j < nv; ++j)
    draw(s.vequals(j), linewidth(0.5));
  draw(s.vequals(nv-.01), linewidth(0.5));
}
```

Have a look at [Niles Johnson's production notes](http://nilesjohnson.net/hopf-production.html). You can see that he took a the time to work out a fairly complex parametrization for the fibers of the Hopf fibration. I would not be surprised if he considered other possible parametrizations, and chose this one precisely because it gives the most visually appealing results. My picture here uses a simpler but less appealing parametrization; the limitation here is not the software, but the time and mental effort required to program in the quaternion-based representation.

Even Niles' color scheme is carefully chosen to be both visually appealing and mathematically meaningful. And in the course of producing and "choreographing" his animation, he no doubt became an expert on any number of ways to fine-tune the appearance of a picture of a Hopf fibration.

There is one important aspect to the software chosen. By using a ray-tracing algorithm, Niles was able to incorporate true shadows into his image, which other kinds of rendering algorithms typically cannot achieve. (Note: ray-tracing is actually a very simple algorithm that produces terrific results, but it is not commonly used by graphing software because it is too resource-intensive to produce, for instance, images that can be rotated interactively.) But the benefits of using the ray-tracing algorithm are secondary to the time and thought that went into constructing the image in the first place.

Answer (score 31):

From the [Wikimedia page](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hopf_Fibration.png#mw-jump-to-license) about that image we learn that it was made with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org). A link to the [author's page](http://nilesjohnson.net/hopf.html) further describes how it was created.

Answer (score 9):

The [image information page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hopf_Fibration.png) claims it is done with Sage. It is part of [this animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk), where your image appears at timestamp 2:27.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it may have been ray traced, a commonly used open source program for ray tracing is povray, it expects all of the geometry to be defined procedurally or mathematically which makes it easier to use for creating images like this.

Answer (score 1):

https://d3x0r.github.io/STFRPhysics/3d/index4.html  (link at bottom to sources)  This isn't as 'beautiful' as raytraced versions, but this is just grabbing a time from 0 to 1 and plotting the points; although this has a line that makes it look iterative, it's actually a direct computation.  The current version only draws 1 fiber, progressively joined to others; and doesn't really have a way to do the nested version (although the same routine could be used with an offset parameter.

This program allows specifying the 3 axis of rotation and showing the resulting Hopf fibration rather than fixed 0-90-90 axii.

[image]

Was playing with building a system using log-quaternions, which are members of so(3) before being put into a matrix and having their information truncated; and this is just one of many explorers.

The yellow segments are segments outside of the rotation matrices used in Lie Algebra; the points that can never be resulted.