# Best Software for Generating Images (Topology)

Tags: soft-question, continuum-theory

I would like to know what people would recommend as the best program to use for generating nice images, particularly of continua.  For example, what's the best program available that makes it easy to make things like something homeomorphic to the topologist's sine-curve, the double topologist's sine-curve, Knaster Buckethandle continuum etc.  I'm wanting the best way to make nice pictures of such planar curves.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to review the items at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525521/what-software-can-draw-pictures-like-this

Comment: That'll do.  Thanks!